# Two different values of the same integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

My question is straightforward. I am getting two different values for the same integral.

```
Integrate[Exp[ (x - I) E^(I z)]/( (x - I) E^(I z)), {z, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
(*Out: 0*)

Integrate[Exp[ (1 - I) E^(I z)]/( (1 - I) E^(I z)), {z, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
(*Out: 2 \[Pi]*)
```

The second integral is the same as the first one, where I just chose $x=1$. I get 0 even if I run

```
Integrate[Exp[ (x - I) E^(I z)]/( (x - I) E^(I z)), {z, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Assumptions -> {x > 0}]
```

What is going on here?

In the following you find my mathematical proof that the integral should be $2\pi$.

For any $x\in \mathbb{C}$, I want to compute

$$
I =\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \frac{e^{xe^{i\theta}}}{xe^{i\theta}}
$$

Parametrizing $x=Re^{i\varphi}$ for some $R\in \mathbb{R}^+$, I can rewrite it as

$$
I = \int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \frac{e^{Re^{i\varphi}e^{i\theta}}}{Re^{i\varphi}e^{i\theta}} = \oint_{C_R} \frac{dz}{i}\frac{e^{ze^{i\varphi}}}{e^{i\varphi}z^2} = 2\pi \sum \text{Res}\left[\frac{e^{z e^{i\varphi}}}{z^2 e^{i\varphi}}\right]
$$

where $z=Re^{i\varphi}$ and $C_R$ is a circle of radius $R$, centered in $z=0$.
The residue is non-vanishing only around on $z=0$, as one can get from the expansion of the exponential around $z=0$

$$
\frac{e^{z e^{i\varphi}}}{z^2 e^{i\varphi}} \sim \frac{1}{e^{i\varphi}z^2}+\frac{1}{z}+...
$$

Therefore, I get $$I=2\pi\,.$$

What is Mathematica doing?

Comment: MA tries to get the antiderivative first. The result contains the [exponential integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/6.3) function `ExpIntegralEi`. It has a  branch-cut discontinuity, which is not properly taken into account.

Comment: @yarchik how do you know that? There is a way to understand what Mathematica is doing? Is this a bug or what?

Comment: I would guess that if MA is able to do the indefinite integration, it uses it in conjunction with the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute the definite integral. One can indeed verify that indefinite integration is possible in your case and it is expressed in terms of the exponential integral. I consider it a bug that MA is not able to detect a discontinuity in it.

Comment: @yarchik thanks for your comment. Notice that the same discrepancy happens if Exp is Substituted with Log or Sin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Mathematica found the anti-derivative of the indefinite integral, then used FTC. But there is a discontinuity  at around `z=3.926990816987` when `x=1` so FTC does not apply for this specific `x`. But since it did not know what `x` could be, it did not know this at the time.

Splitting the integration to avoid this, gives `2 Pi`.

I can't find the exact location of the this, but it is between `z=3.926990816987` and `z=3.926990816988`

```
 left = 3926990816987/(10^12);
 right = 3926990816988/(10^12);

res = Integrate[Exp[(x - I) E^(I z)]/((x - I) E^(I z)), {z, 0, left}] 
   + 
  Integrate[Exp[(x - I) E^(I z)]/((x - I) E^(I z)), {z, right, 2 Pi}];

Chop[Limit[res, x -> 1]]

(*6.28319*)

 2 Pi // N
(*6.28319*)
```

Or

```
 Simplify[(res /. x -> 1) - 2 Pi] // N // Chop
 (* 0 *)
```

You'll get zero, if you do not avoid this "pole" like you had, since your integration intervals was from `0` to `2 Pi`

Showing discontinuity on anti-derivative when `x=1`

```
integrand = Exp[(x - I) E^(I z)]/((x - I) E^(I z));
r = Limit[Integrate[(integrand), z], x -> 1];
Plot[Re[r], {z, 0, 2 Pi}, Exclusions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the problem is that, for some specific `x` values, FTC do not apply. Hence taking limits can give wrong result.

I would say this looks like a bug.

```
integrand = Exp[(x - I) E^(I z)]/((x - I) E^(I z));
r = Integrate[(integrand), z];
(Limit[r, z -> 2 Pi] - Limit[r, z -> 0]) // Simplify
(* 0 *)
```

The above uses FTC. This assumes anti-derivative is continuous over the interval. But for specific `x` values, this is not true.  This is the main issue.

> So, is this a bug?

I'll let the experts at WRI decide this. Please send report to support@wri.com.

It is probably very hard to know if there is pole or not given that `x` does not have numerical value. That is why when you gave specific value for `x` it did it correctly.

But FriCAS for example refused to integrate this giving "Potential Pole" and opted out.

```
6) -> integrate(exp((x-%i)*exp(%i*z))/((x-%i)*exp(%i*z)),z=0..2*%pi)
   (6)  "potentialPole"
```

I would say in general it is better not to return result, than return one which is not correct.

### small note

Here is much simpler example

```
 Integrate[Exp[x E^(I z)], {z, 0, 2 Pi}]
 (*0 if x==0*)
```

And

```
  Integrate[Exp[x E^(I z)] /. x -> 1, {z, 0, 2 Pi}]
  (* 2 Pi*)
```

Notice the solution for the first case above, it used a specific `x` value, but did not say what will happen for `x` other than zero, say for `x=1`. Because when `x=1`, FTC do not apply, there is discontinuity at `x=Pi`

```
  r = Integrate[Exp[x E^(I z)], z]
  (*-I ExpIntegralEi[E^(I z) x]*)

  Plot[Re[r /. x -> 1], {z, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So may be for your example, Mathematica just needed to add `Conditional` for its zero result, and it missed to do this. If it had `Conditional` like in this example, then it would have been correct answer.

So the buttom line I would say is that result of integration being `0` is correct but for some **specific** `x` value and not for any `x` value in general. And Mathematica should have mentioned this in its answer to be correct like in this small example.

Comment: Thanks. So, is this a bug? For instance, the same discrepancy happens by replacing Exp with Log or Sin

Comment: @apt45 I answered above.

Comment: The discontinuity at 3.9269908169... is actually $5\pi/4$

Comment: @flinty that is good. I did not know how to find it. too lazy to try, so just did numerical approximation.

Comment: Thanks @flinty! What is the origin of this discontinuity?

Comment: The imaginary part of the function is zero at this value, and the real part is $-\frac{e^{-\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{2}}$ - the function is smooth so that's not the problem. In fact the discontinuity is in the antiderivative, specifically the `ExpIntegralEi` part - try plotting `Im[ExpIntegralEi[(1 - I) E^(I z)]]` and the $5\pi/4$  discontinuity appears. This could be because `(1 - I) E^(I z)` is $-\sqrt{2}$ at this point. Look at the big $\pi$ sized jump in imaginary part between `N@ExpIntegralEi[-1]` and `N@ExpIntegralEi[-1 + I*$MachineEpsilon]`. It's a mystery to me why `ExpIntegralEi` does this.

Comment: ah right it's right there in the docs, my bad. _ExpIntegralEi[z] has a branch cut discontinuity in the complex z plane running from -\[Infinity] to 0_

Comment: @flinty Ok thanks!

Comment: This analysis is correct. For further details here is what is in the bug report. "Integrate simply does not know how to handle the parametrized branch cut in the antiderivative. It correctly assesses that any point on the integration path where Im[x] Cos[z] - Cos[z] + Re[x] Sin[z] is 0 and Cos[z] Re[x] + Sin[z] - Im[x] Sin[z] is a negative real will be a singular point. But it does not know how to proceed with that for purposes of evaluating the antiderivative as such points are approached."